# Troubleshooting åäö to Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

The problem:

An input of åäö in  insert Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶ in db. The file is in UTF-8 without BOM and comment in the table has utf8_general_ci coallition.

The code:

```
<?php
    if($_POST['comment']!=''){

            $comment=addcslashes($_POST['comment'], "\x00\n\r\'\x1a\x3c\x3e\x25");


            if($kommentar!=''){
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (comment) VALUES ('$comment')") or die(mysql_error());

            }
        }
    ?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="sv">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    //Form
    </body>
```

Background:

Earlier I performed htmlentities on the $_POST['comment']; before inserting to db, and outputted directly, which worked fine. Then I wanted to go best practise and input raw data (just cleaning) and o htmlentities (or similar) on output. But then I discovered that e.g. åäö is not inputted as åäö but as Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶. Heeeelp :)

Comment: Do not use `addcslashes` to escape the comment -  `mysql_real_escape_string()` is the one right way to sanitize a string in this case.

Comment: @Pekka I changed it but it did not address the problem unfortunately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to set the connection's collation to UTF-8, which is iso-8859-1 by default.
Try

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

after connecting to the database.

Comment: I added it like following and will keep it but it did not solve the problem unfortnately: $connect = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die();
mysql_select_db($database , $connect) or die();
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$connect);

Comment: @Joseph it *could* be that you are using mySQL < 5.0.7. In that case, try `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");` instead. Does that work? Where are you outputting the data?

Comment: @Pekka I tried it but I have the same result. Though it have to be something with that since echoing the string gives "åäö" but interting it gives the Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶. Am I adding it right? See comment above: That is in my config file, dshould it be there or after every query?

Comment: @Joseph I'm fairly sure  it's the connection collation, but I don't understand why neither command is changing it. Is what you are showing your full code? You are not doing anything else with the characters? Because the code you show can't work (It's "kommentar" in one, and "comment" in the other)

Comment: @Pekka it is correct in the file, I just missed out to translate them in the post.

Comment: @Pekka your solution worked the testing output didnt had utf8 specified in the htmlentities, so the result did not show there but in the db. Thanks!